# C programming - segmentation fault (core dump)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am continuously getting a seg fault (core dump) each time that I run it, no matter what I change or the fact that is compiling fine! Not sure where I am making the mistake? Any suggestions?

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *output;
    if ((output = fopen("output", "w")) == NULL)
    {
            printf ("cannot open the file input\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int data = 1;
    while (scanf("%d", data) > 0)
    {
            print(output, data);
    }

    fclose(output);
    return (0);
}
void print(FILE* output, int data)
{
    fprintf(output, "%d\n", data);
    return;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` expect address `scanf("%d", &data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 change `while (scanf("%d", data) > 0)` to `while (scanf("%d", &data) > 0)` .

2 move the function of `print` to the begin.

This could work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

void print(FILE* output, int data)
{
    fprintf(output, "%d\n", data);
    return;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *output;
    if ((output = fopen("output", "w")) == NULL)
    {
            printf ("cannot open the file input\n");
            return -1;
    }

    int data = 1;
    while (scanf("%d", &data) > 0)
    {
            print(output, data);
    }

    fclose(output);
    return (0);
}
```

#### Input

1 2 3  "Enter"  "Ctrl+D"

Comment: I think this helped, but it will still not print to the output file.  Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: @mega.rose You should use "Ctrl + D" to complete the entry. And I edit my answer to add an example of the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (scanf("%d", data) > 0)
```

should be changed to

```
while (scanf("%d", &data) > 0)
```

as scanf expects address of variable to be passed not the variable itself, if you pass a variable , scanf will end up accessing wrong memory by considering the value you passed as memory address, this will lead to undefined behavour

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as someone said here before, you need to pass an adress of a variable to scanf function, so it looks like this:

```
    scanf("%d", &data)
```

But using it in a while loop like you do won't work correctly, since scanf does not return a value you assign to a variable.
You have to use it like this:

```
   while(data > 0)
   {
       scanf("%d", &data);
       print(output, data);
   }
```

And in this case, I believe a do-while loop is more suitable, rather than while loop:

```
   do
   {
       scanf("%d", &data);
       print(output, data);
   } while (data > 0);
```

This way it will work the way You expect it to work.

You also forgot to specify a filetype of Your output file:

```
    if ((output = fopen("output", "w")) == NULL)
```

should probably be

```
    if ((output = fopen("output.txt", "w")) == NULL)
```

I posted a complete solution for You here: https://pastebin.com/vpK9i6Wk